# How to view or edit sqlite db records on cloud9 ide?

Tags: sqlite, cloud9-ide

Given a sqlite db (i.e. 'development.sqlite3') file, how do I view or edit the records in that database file on cloud9?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it on your workspace by going to the terminal and typing in:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

once installed, just type in `sqlite3 <path to development.sqlite3>` which will bring up the SQLite cli that you can use to view and edit records.

Comment: At this time, both of those are installed by default on c9.io